# How can I use IF statement in sql stored-procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to transform an SQL Query to a procedure in SQL server, but I have an issue in the IF statement.

This is the logic I want to implement:

```
//If the patientStatus equals "all" there will be no condition

patientStatus.ToString() == "all" ? "" :
(
      patientStatus.ToString() == "out" 
      ? " AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NOT NULL" 
      :" AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NULL "
)
```

After searching about how to use IF statement in Stored Procedures, I came out with this, but **it has errors**:

```
IF(@PATIENT_STATUS != 'all')
 BEGIN
   if(@PATIENT_STATUS = 'out')
     BEGIN
       AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NOT NULL
     END
    else
      BEGIN
       AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NULL
      END       
  END
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Matt, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. and Incorrect syntax near 'CMS_ENCOUNTER'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `AND` and `OR` conditions to get the result you desire. You can use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename AS CMS_ENCOUNTER
WHERE 
    (@PATIENT_STATUS = 'all') OR
    (@PATIENT_STATUS = 'out' AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NOT NULL) OR 
    (@PATIENT_STATUS <> 'out' AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NULL)
```

In this case first you evaluate condition `@PATIENT_STATUS = 'all'`. If it evaluates to true, you get all results. If it evaluates to false, only then other conditions are evaluated.

Second condition (`(@PATIENT_STATUS = 'out' AND CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NOT NULL)` is evaluated only when patient status is `out`, otherwise the third condition is evaluated.

Comment: I will pass the value of @PATIENT_STATUS, and each case will has it's own condition (out, in, all). If it was "all' I will return all patients, otherwise I will return specific type of patients.

Comment: @HasanKhatib That is fine, if `@PATIENT_STATUS = 'all'`, then you will retrieve all results. Otherwise you get filtered results

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that :

```
AND CASE 
        WHEN @PATIENT_STATUS = 'all' THEN 1 = 1
        WHEN @PATIENT_STATUS = 'out' THEN CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NOT NULL
        ELSE CMS_ENCOUNTER.ENCOUNTER_END_TIME IS NULL
    END
```